# A pseudo Fejér-Jackson inequality problem

Tags: analysis, inequality, trigonometry

$x\in (0,\pi)$
,Prove that:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sin{kx}}{k}>x\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^3
\end{align}

the inequality holds for all integer $n$

I tried Fourier, or Dirichlet kernel, but they don't work.Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Please state where this problem from.

Comment: while proving the Fejér-Jackson inequality, from http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=114058 5 floor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This left hand side is simply the Fourier series of a [Sawtooth wave](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html). All you now have to do is prove that the polynomial to the right is smaller then the straight line.

Comment: How to compare the partial sum of the Fourier series with a polynomial?

Comment: @Golbez - You may find this helpfull as well:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57054/asymptotic-error-of-fourier-series-partial-sum-of-sawtooth-function