# Inequality $\sum\limits_{1\le k\le n}\frac{\sin kx}{k}\ge 0$ (Fejer-Jackson)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

Show the following inequality for any $x\in [0, \pi]$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$,
$$
\sum_{1\le k\le n}\frac{\sin kx}{k}\ge 0.
$$

I have this question a very long time ago from a book or magazine but I cannot solve it by myself and did not know how to solve it until today.

My try: for $n=1, 2, 3$, one can check this by hand.

Comment: You can write $\sin(xk) = \mathcal{Im}(e^{ixk)}$, but the result will involve transcendent functions

Comment: @Alex That seems not helpful for the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**In short:** let $f_n(x)$ denote the function on the lhs of the inequality. Of course, $f_1(x)=\sin x\geq 0$ on $[0,\pi]$. We will prove that $f_n(x)\geq 0$ on $[0,\pi]$ by induction on $n$. It is not too hard to determine the local minima of $f_n$ on $[0,\pi]$ by investigating its derivative. Then Ma Ming observed that $f_n$ coincides with $f_{n-1}$ on these local minima. And the induction step follows easily. Of course, $f_n(0)=f_n(\pi)=0$. We will actually prove that

> $$
> f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin kx}{k}>0\qquad\forall x\in(0,\pi).
> $$

**Remark:** it is worth noting that the $f_n$'s are the partial sums of the Fourier series of the same sawtooth function. Just [look at the case $n=6$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%20%28x%29%2bsin%20%282x%29/2%2bsin%20%283x%29/3%2bsin%20%284x%29/4%2bsin%285x%29/5%2bsin%286x%29/6), for instance, to see how they tend to approximate it nicely. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57054/asymptotic-error-of-fourier-series-partial-sum-of-sawtooth-function) to get an idea how to estimate the error in such approximations. As pointed out by math110, there are many proofs of this so-called Fejer-Jackson inequality. It can even be shown that the [$f_n$'s are bounded below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177995/a-pseudo-fejer-jackson-inequality-problem) by a certain nonnegative polynomial on $[0,\pi]$. The proof below is at the calculus I level. I'm not sure it can be made more elementary.

**Proof:** first, $f_1(x)=\sin x$ is positive on $(0,\pi)$. Assume this holds for $f_{n-1}$ for some $n\geq 2$. Then observe that $f_n$ is differenbtiable on $\mathbb{R}$ with
$$
f_n'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\cos kx=\mbox{Re} \sum_{k=1}^n (e^{ix})^k.
$$
For $x\in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}$, we have $f_n'(x)=n$. So the zeros of $f_n'$ are the zeros of 
$$
\mbox{Re}\;e^{ix}\frac{e^{inx}-1}{e^{ix}-1}=\mbox{Re}\;e^{i(n+1)x/2}\frac{\sin (nx/2)}{\sin(x/2)}=\frac{\cos((n+1)x/2)\sin (nx/2)}{\sin(x/2)}.
$$
This yields 
$$
\frac{nx}{2}\in \pi\mathbb{Z}\quad\mbox{or}\quad \frac{(n+1)x}{2}\in \frac{\pi}{2}+\pi\mathbb{Z}
$$
i.e.
$$
x\in \frac{2\pi}{n}\mathbb{Z}\quad\mbox{or}\quad x\in \frac{\pi}{n+1}+\frac{2\pi}{n+1}\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Between $0$ and $\pi$, these are ordered as follows:
$$
0<\frac{\pi}{n+1}<\frac{2\pi}{n}<\frac{3\pi}{n+1}<\frac{4\pi}{n}<\ldots  < \frac{2\lfloor n/2\rfloor \pi}{n}\leq \pi.
$$
The sign of $f_n'$ changes at each of these zeros, starting from a positive sign on $(0,\pi/(n+1))$. It follows that $f_n$ is positive on the latter, positive on the last interval (if nontrivial, i.e. in the odd case), with local minima at 
$$\frac{2j\pi}{n}\qquad\mbox{for}\qquad j=1,\ldots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor.$$

But now here is Ma Ming's key observation: for these values, we have
$$
f_n\left(\frac{2j\pi}{n}\right)=f_{n-1}\left(\frac{2j\pi}{n}\right)+\sin\left(n\cdot\frac{2j\pi}{n}\right)=f_{n-1}\left(\frac{2j\pi}{n}\right)>0
$$
by induction step. It follows that $f_n(x)>0$ on $(0,\pi)$. QED.

Comment: Great. I already proved it. The last inequality for specific $x$ can be done by a simple induction on $n$, the last term $\sin nx \ge 0$!

Comment: You mean, using what I did? Then just edit my answer. I'll make it CW.

Comment: @MaMing Good observation. There is a problem with your inequality for the local maxima, but we don't need them. We only need to check that the local minima ar $\geq 0$. I'll edit.

Answer (score 8):

This is Fejer-Jackson inequality: This problem has some nice solutions, you can see  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=114058

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

Some years ago, I saw a nice solution in a Chinese forum.
I do not know the original source. I translated it and
rewrote it compactly. I give it here.

**Problem**: Let $0 < x < \pi$ and $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that
$$\sin x+\dfrac{\sin 2x}{2}+\dfrac{\sin 3x}{3}+\ldots+ \dfrac{\sin nx}{n}>0.$$

**Proof**:  Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that
there exists $y\in (0, \pi)$ satisfying $\sum_{k=1}^m \dfrac{\sin ky}{k} \le 0$. Clearly $m \ge 2$.

Let $f(x) := \sum_{k=1}^m \dfrac{\sin kx}{k}$. Since $f(y) \le 0 = f(0) = f(\pi)$, there exists $z\in (0, \pi)$ which is a global minimizer of $f(x)$ on $[0,\pi]$ (see Remark 1 at the end).
Thus, we have $f'(z) = 0$ and $f(z) \le 0$.

We claim that $\sin m z < 0$.
Indeed, if $\sin mz \ge 0$, using $0 \ge f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \dfrac{\sin k z}{k} + \frac{\sin m z}{m}$,
we have $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \dfrac{\sin k z}{k} \le 0$.
This contradicts the smallestness of $m$.

It follows from $\sin m z < 0$ that
$\sin \frac{mz}{2} \ne 0$ and $\cos\frac{(m+1)z}{2} \ne 0$ (see Remark 2 at the end) which contradicts
$$0 = f'(z) = \sum_{k=1}^m \cos kz = \frac{\cos\frac{(m+1)z}{2}\sin \frac{mz}{2}}{\sin \frac{z}{2}}.$$
This completes the proof.

**Remark 1**: Let $f^\ast$ be the minimum of $f(x)$ on $[0, \pi]$.
If $f^\ast < 0$, since $f(0) = f(\pi) = 0$, the minimum of $f(x)$
on $[0, \pi]$ occurs on $(0,\pi)$.
If $f^\ast = 0$, since $f(y) \le 0$, $y$ is a global minimizer.

**Remark 2**:
$$\sin \frac{mz}{2} = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow\quad \sin mz = 0,$$
and
\begin{align}
\cos\frac{(m+1)z}{2} = 0\quad & \Longrightarrow \quad
\exists N\in \mathbb{Z},\ (m+1)z = (2N+1)\pi \\
&\Longrightarrow \quad
\sin mz = \sin ((2N+1)\pi - z) = \sin z \ge 0 .
\end{align}
Contradiction.

Comment: Nice solution! Let me ask you a small question please: You wrote that $f(z)\leq 0$. I cannot get it.

Comment: @ZFR Thanks. Since $f(y) \le 0$ and $f(z)$ is the global minimum of $f(x)$ on $[0, \pi]$, we have $f(z) \le f(y) \le 0$.

Comment: One moment is a bit confusing to me: Since $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$ then it has global minimum $z\in [0,\pi]$ by Weierstrass theorem. If $z\in (0,\pi)$ then we can conclude that $f'(z)=0$ by Fermat's theorem. How do you know that $z$ is not one of the endpoints?

Comment: I still cannot get your point. You claim that global minimum of $f(x)$ lies in $(0,\pi)$, right?  I don't think that your reasoning is clear enough.

Comment: @ZFR Since $f(0) = f(\pi) = 0$, if there is a point $f(w) < 0$ with $w\in (0, \pi)$, then the global minimum of $f(x)$ on $[0, \pi]$ does not occur at endpoints (since $f(0) = f(\pi) = 0$), right?

Comment: @ZFR If there is no $w\in (0, \pi)$ such that $f(w) < 0$, then $f(x) \ge 0$ for $[0, \pi]$, then since $f(y) \le 0$, so $y$ is a global minimizer.

Comment: @ZFR Another explanation: Since $f(0) = f(\pi) = 0$ and $f(y) \le 0$ ($y\in (0, \pi)$), we know that there always exists at least a point in $(0, \pi)$ whose function value is less than or equal to the function values of the endpoints. So there exists $z\in (0, \pi)$ which is the global minimizer of $f(x)$ on $[0, \pi]$ (However, perhaps the endpoints are also a global minimizer, not unique).

Comment: I'd prefer this reasoning: Let's prove that the global minimum(let's denote it by $z$) of $f(x)$ lies in $(0,\pi)$. We have two possible cases: 1) There is $w\in [0,\pi]$ such that $f(w)<0$. Since $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$ then $w\in (0,\pi)$. Then $z$ which is global minimum of $f$ lies in $(0,\pi)$ and $f(z)<0$. 2) For each $w\in [0,\pi]$ we have $f(w)\geq 0$. Then $f(y)=0$ and $z=y$, i.e. $y$ is global minimum.

Comment: And a small remark: In the above proof $m$ should be $>1$.

Comment: @ZFR $\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{\sin k y}{y} \le 0$ and $y\in (0, \pi)$ implies $m > 1$. Indeed, if $m = 1$, then $\sin y \le 0$ and $y\in (0, \pi)$ which is impossible.

Comment: @ZFR Thanks for your detailed comments. I will try to edit my text soon.

Comment: Your solution is really nice! But I guess with those details it's gonna be perfect. Thank you so much for explanation!

Comment: @ZFR Thank you very much for the valuable comments and suggestion.

Comment: Sorry but how it follows that $\sin mz<0$? why do we have strict inequality? Not so clear.

Comment: @ZFR Thanks for comment. I will edit it soon.