# $\frac{\cos x}{1}+\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}+\cdots+\frac{\cos (nx)}{n}\gt -1$ is true for $n\in\mathbb N, 0\lt x\lt \pi$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, summation

Let $n$ be a natural number and let $0\lt x\lt{\pi}$. Then, here are my questions.

> **Question 1** : Is the following true?
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}\gt -1$$
>
> **Question 2** : Is the following true?
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}\gt0$$

**Motivation** : I've known the smaller $n$ cases. These seems true by using computer. I would like to know not only whether there are true but also how to prove that. Can you help?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376273/inequality-sum-1-le-k-le-n-frac-sin-kxk-ge-0?rq=1).

Comment: @julien: Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1** is Young inequality(1912);can see 
http://sci-prew.inf.ua/v134/1/S0305004102006357.pdf

and can see Young's paper(1912),But I can't download:http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-12/1/41.extract