# Use summation by parts to show with certainty that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\sin k)/k>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Summation by parts: Let $\{a_k\}$ and $\{b_k\}$ be arbitrary sequences of real numbers, and let $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$. Then for $0\le m< n$,

$\sum\limits_{k=m}^na_kb_k=s_nb_n-s_{m-1}b_m+\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n-1}s_k(b_k-b_{k+1})$

The series $t=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\sin k)/k$ converges. Use summation by parts to show with certainty that $t>0$.

I am not sure how to show this but here is my start:

Let $b_k=\frac{1}{k}$ and $a_k=\sin k$. Also $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\sin k$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Note $|\sum_{k=1}^n|\le\csc(1/2)$.

Then

$\sum\limits_{k=m}^n\frac{1}{k}\sin k=(\sum_{k=1}^n\sin k)\cdot\frac{1}{n}-(\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\sin k)\cdot\frac{1}{m}+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}(\sum_{j=1}^k\sin j)(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})$

How can I introduce the $|\sum_{k=1}^n|\le\csc(1/2)$? and then use that to show that $t>0$?

Comment: Related: [$\sum_{1\le k\le n}\frac{\sin kx}{k}\ge 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376273/inequality-sum-1-le-k-le-n-frac-sin-kxk-ge-0)