# Help me please, A0 fourier series for this Sawtooth wave

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I need to know for this wave sub zero, the correct answer is a0=-2V/Pi, but I do not know how to get to that answer. Help me please the imagen its the series.

This is the sawtooth wave
http://s9.postimage.org/42uc7x0pp/IMG00030_20121012_1152.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: Destructive edit rolled back.

Comment: @5pm: How did you even come across this thread?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Bumped to the front page by Community (before I upvoted the answer to keep the bot quiet).

Comment: @5pm: Ah. If only these autobumps were documents... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave

[Asymptotic error of Fourier series partial sum of sawtooth function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57054/asymptotic-error-of-fourier-series-partial-sum-of-sawtooth-function?rq=1)

$$\{x\}=\frac{1}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\sin 2\pi nx}{\pi n}+O((1+||x||N)^{-1})
= \frac{1}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin 2\pi nx}{\pi n}$$

Comment: Thanks but No, the answer for this wave its **-2V/pi +(sen wt+1 + sen wt+2...)** see? **My problem its how to solve A0, A0 its -2V/pi how to?** thanks!